# NativeScript zIndex set in XML not working?

Tags: nativescript

Consider the next xml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" >
  <!-- UI Decalration -->
    <AbsoluteLayout>
      <GridLayout zIndex="99" height="100" width="100" backgroundColor="red"></GridLayout>
      <GridLayout zIndex="1" height="200" width="200" backgroundColor="green"></GridLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</Page>
```

In my understanding the red square should be visible, but it's hidden behind the green one. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just change the order of the gridLayouts, then the last element will be on top. Maybe you can set the z-index in the style/css?

Comment: And be aware of that the z-index is only supported at Android API level 21 at this moment. http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/styling.html#supported-css-properties

Answer (score 4):

Declare z-index as CSS property so all elements should be rendered as espected.
For example :

page.css

```
.lower-grid {
    z-index: 1;
}
.upper-grid {
    z-index: 99;
}
```

page.xml

```
  <AbsoluteLayout>
      <GridLayout class="upper-grid" height="100" width="100" backgroundColor="red" />
      <GridLayout class="lower-grid" height="200" width="200" backgroundColor="green" />
  </AbsoluteLayout>
```

This solution worked out for me - keep in mind that z-index is supported for Android API 21 and above.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question to not confuse people. The css property does work. So, I'm giving you a vote. What I'm interested in is why javascript property is not working.

Comment: It's a bug that I have just reported in https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues and its already been scheduled for fixing.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by using gridlayout and then repeating the same row number. The order of the items then determines the z-index [playground demo](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=rbeKKL):

```
<GridLayout rows="*, *, *" columns="*">
    <GridLayout row="0" col="0" height="300" backgroundColor="black" />
    <GridLayout row="1" col="0" height="300" backgroundColor="red" />
    <GridLayout row="2" col="0" height="300" backgroundColor="green" />
    <GridLayout row="0" col="0" height="100" backgroundColor="blue" margin="100" /> <!-- displays on top of the first row 0 -->
</GridLayout>
```